# receber emails utilizando o R

Tags: r, email

Já fiz varias pesquisas e encontro muita informação de como enviar e-mail pelo R, mas não encontrei nada de como receber e-mail pelo R. Não encontrei nem ao menos uma biblioteca para eu começar a desenvolver alguma coisa. Alguém conhece alguma biblioteca ou tem um exemplo de como receber emails pelo R?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar puxar mensagens do Gmail, por exemplo, (SSL) usando Python e o pacote `rJython`. O Jython é implementado em Python na máquina virtual Java, portanto, usar rJython assemelha-se um pouco como usar R para chamar Java. Além disso, só conheço o pacote `mailR`, mas este apenas envia e-mails por enquanto. Você pode consultar um exemplo do `rJython` aqui -> [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241812/how-can-i-send-receive-smtp-pop3-email-using-r)